# How to stretch the WAV file to the same video length?

Tags: ffmpeg

So yeah, having a tricky ffmpeg issue here.

In my app I'm encoding a video based on image frames and add a WAV file for the sound from the same source but through a different web socket. It can happen that the WAV file doesn't always have exactly the same length as the video based on those images + fps (plus minus few seconds).

How can I tell ffmpeg to "stretch" the input WAV file to have it the same length as the video?

In short: `images (i) + WAV (w) = final video (v)`

`length(w) != length (v)` ... which is causing problems.

Here an example ffmpeg command I am currently using:

> ffmpeg -f image2 -thread_queue_size 512 -framerate 21.5 -i
>   /frames/%d.webp -i videomail_preview.wav -y -acodec aac -strict
>   experimental -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 16 -preset fast -profile:v
>   baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart
>   videomail_good.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -ac 1 -vcodec libvpx -crf 8
>   -deadline good -cpu-used 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart videomail_good.webm

And here the ffmpeg version + its extensions

> ffmpeg version 2.8.6-1ubuntu2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the
>   FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-11ubuntu1)
>   20160311 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2
>   --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100 libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100 libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101 libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100 libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101 libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.
>   1.  0 libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101 libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101 libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

Any suggestions/trick I am unaware of?

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your command: it will show if your `ffmpeg` supports librubberband.

Comment: oh, added the ffmpeg config output. dont have librubberband in it. would librubberband help solving my issue?

Comment: I was hoping to see the complete console output so I could give you an exact answer with the correct filter values, but Behroozfar provided an answer that you can adapt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rubberband will probably sound better than [atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo); especially for larger ratio differences. If you want to use rubberband but don't have support for this filter in your `ffmpeg` (and don't want to [compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)), then you can use the [standalone `rubberband` tool](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/index.html).

## `rubberband` example

```
rubberband -D 12 input.wav output.wav
```

- `-D<X>`, `--duration <X>` - Stretch or squash to make output file X seconds long

See `rubberband -h` or [`rubberband` command line utility help text](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/documentation.html) for more info.

## Step by step process

Unfortunately this won't be a single command. Using this method you will have to:

1. Encode the video.
2. [Get the video duration with `ffprobe`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).
3. Generate the audio with `rubberband`.
4. Mux the video and audio:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video -i audio -c copy -shortest output
   ```

#### Additional notes

- `-movflags +faststart` Is suitable for MP4, but is ignored by the webm muxer.
- FFmpeg version 2.8.6 is old. Users are recommended to use a build from the current git master branch. The easiest solution is to [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a static build, but you can [compile](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) if you prefer. Compiling will allow you to use the [rubberband filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband) in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: An old version? Well I installed it via apt-get from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 ... there is no newer version I can install via apt-get at the moment

Comment: i wonder if there is a newer apt-get package that also comes with the rubberband tool?

Comment: @MichaelHeuberger rubberband-cli is available, but you don't have to use an old `ffmpeg` from a repo. Just [download](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a standalone binary.

Comment: bumped to ubuntu 16.10 which comes with ffmpeg v3 shipped and that worked

Comment: but i realise this is making my code a lot more complicated. isn't there a trick just to run this all within a single ffmpeg command?

Comment: @MichaelHeuberger No, unless you know ahead of time the duration of the video created from the images (which is *number of frames* / *frame rate*) **and** if you have rubberband support in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: now i got it all working very well for my app www.videomail.io (audio + video are in sync now) - thanks again for your help

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 option in FFMPEG Audio filters that may help you: in both scenario you must manually calculate the ratio of RATIO=(VIDEO_DURATION/AUDIO_DURATION) and put it in command.

1. `atempo` : with this filter you can speed up or slow down your audio. for your goal `ffmpeg -f image2 -thread_queue_size 512 -framerate 21.5 -i /frames/%d.webp -i videomail_preview.wav -y -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 16 -preset fast -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart -filter:a "atempo=RATIO" videomail_good.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -ac 1 -vcodec libvpx -crf 8 -deadline good -cpu-used 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart -filter:a "atempo=RATIO" videomail_good.webm`. *IMPORTANT note* : The atempo filter is limited to using values between 0.5 and 2.0. If you need to, you can get around this limitation by stringing multiple atempo filters together.
2. `rubberband` : with this, you can have more control on stretching your audio in compare with `atempo` filter. one basic command is : `ffmpeg -f image2 -thread_queue_size 512 -framerate 21.5 -i /frames/%d.webp -i videomail_preview.wav -y -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 16 -preset fast -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart -filter:a "rubberband=tempo=RATIO" videomail_good.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -ac 1 -vcodec libvpx -crf 8 -deadline good -cpu-used 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags +faststart -filter:a "rubberband=tempo=RATIO" videomail_good.webm`. this filter has more options such as `pitch`, `transients`, `channels` and more.

Comment: is there no way i can do this in one command that also includes ratio calculations?

Comment: "basic command" :D

Comment: @Daniel Lol, it's not so basic!

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mkv
```