# how do I install rubberband

Tags: sync

I have some audio and video files I've been muxing together but one of them seems to be beyond what ffmpeg can do. Changing the tempo of the audio and/or shifting the start of the audio compared to the video isn't working; the audio is off in the middle of the video even if correct at the start and end (like it is warped). After some reading (here: [How to stretch the WAV file to the same video length?](https://superuser.com/questions/1131923/how-to-stretch-the-wav-file-to-the-same-video-length)) I think Rubberband might work better as messing with the tempo still results in a audio stream that is longer than the video. I think I can use the duration command to straight up tell the audio to be the same length as the video. Problem is, I've downloaded Rubberband, double-clicked on the exe file, saw it do something in command prompt, but I can't seem to get any command to work. Do I need to activate it in cmd? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Rubberband is a command line interface program, meaning you run it in cmd. Open the cmd in the folder with the rubberband.exe(to navigate cmd see https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-from-right-click-menu).

In the command line(cmd), you run programs with their filename and adding parameters.

Running the example in the Readme would look like this (it changes the duration by 1.5 and the pitch by 2.0 semitones):

C:\Users\.. ..\rubberband-3.1.0> rubberband -t 1.5 -p 2.0 test.wav output.wav

For the full list of commands see the documentation https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/usage.txt